# Desktop IDE-Style Layouts on the Web

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am making a single-page, full-screen web application which will have a similar interface to an IDE (with menus at the top, output pane on the bottom, and input panes tiled horizontally across the middle). I am targeting only modern browsers, so a solution that uses HTML5 would be fine. Is there a good JavaScript framework and/or CSS framework to make creation of the layout easier?

**Update:** To clarify, I am looking for tools to make the single-page, full-screen layout practical, not the controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try http://dhtmlx.com/

For a living exemple of what you want to do, try this apps : http://c9.io/ It uses  ACE : http://ace.ajax.org/

Comment: Yeah the name is not very appropriate but it's an HTML5 framework.

Comment: It doesn't even have a github :(

Answer (score 3):

Tons.  ExtJS, jquery UI, YUI can do it, dojo can do it, many, many others.

Comment: and [smart client](http://www.smartclient.com/product/scOverview.jsp) which is one of the best around if you ask me.

Comment: I tried to find examples of this in jQuery UI, but I can't seem to find what it offers that makes this easier to do.

Comment: It gives you a lot of the common widgets that you'd expect an IDE to have; accordions, treeviews, as well as dragging and dropping for moving windows around.  it doesn't do it all for you (though you could get close by adding some plugins), but it does make things easier, which is what you asked for.